Imported SAS file into R, combining columns of different length
I’m very new to programming with R. Ive imported SAS data into R. I have 4 data frames (for the sake of my question I only included 2) with some containing the same sequence numbers. I need to extract the sequence number without duplicating it and the information that is with it and combine it with another data.frame (again without duplicating).
I heard the “for” loop might work?
Any help is appreciated
I tried merge and cbind (both aren’t working because of the different length columns of data:
I have:
Data1:
Seq:      Age:
12345      35
23456      25

Data2:
Seq:       Weight:
12345      178
23456      145
34567      200


I need:
Seq:       Age:      Weight:
12345       35        178
23456       25        145
34567       <NA>      200  


merge(Data1, Data2, by="Seq", all=TRUE) ?

@Edward merge(Data1, Data2, all=TRUE) should be sufficient, not having to specify the by columns (if there's no conlfict) is actually the highlight of merge. People often expend themselves unnecessarily with this and make mistakes.

@jay.sf For this tiny toy data example, you are correct. But I suspect that the OP has many more columns, so I included  the "by" argument as a precaution. Better safe than sorry. The simplest code is not always the best in SO. ;)
